# How to convert world rotation to screen rotation?

Tags: three.js

I need to convert the position and rotation on a 3d object to screen position and rotation. I can convert the position easily but not the rotation. I've attempted to convert the rotation of the camera but it does not match up.

Attached is an example plunkr & conversion code.

The white facebook button should line up with the red plane.

https://plnkr.co/edit/0MOKrc1lc2Bqw1MMZnZV?p=preview

```
function toScreenPosition(position, camera, width, height) {
    var p = new THREE.Vector3(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    var vector = p.project(camera);
    vector.x = (vector.x + 1) / 2 * width;
    vector.y = -(vector.y - 1) / 2 * height;

    return vector;
}

function updateScreenElements() {
    var btn = document.querySelector('#btn-share')
    var pos = plane.getWorldPosition();
    var vec = toScreenPosition(pos, camera, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var translate = "translate3d("+vec.x+"px,"+vec.y+"px,"+vec.z+"px)";
    var euler = camera.getWorldRotation();
    var rotate = "rotateX("+euler.x+"rad)"+
      " rotateY("+(euler.y)+"rad)"+
      " rotateY("+(euler.z)+"rad)";

    btn.style.transform= translate+ " "+rotate;
}
```

... And a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

Comment: That is what `CSS3DRenderer` is for. See the 'sandbox' example [here](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=css3d). Show the updated plnkr if you get it working. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend not trying to match this to the camera space, but instead to apply the image as a texture map to the red plane, and then use a raycast to see whether a click goes over the plane. You'll save yourself headache in translating and rotating and then hiding the symbol when it's behind the cube, etc

[check out the THREEjs examples to see how to use the Raycaster.](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_terrain_raycast) It's a lot more flexible and easier than trying to do rotations and matching. Then whatever the 'btn' onclick function is, you just call when you detect a raycast collision with the plane